# Using ASP classic to produce a label template for printing

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, mailmerge

I have a problem that I'm not sure how to approach. Here is some background:

- We are using a web application that can be extended with ASP classic and JavaScript
- The web app contains details of clients
- Users of the web app need to be able to print an address label for a specified client
- The user needs to specify which label on the sheet will be used

Now I can get all the information that I need about the client and which label is to be used next but I have no idea how I should go about printing the label. I have an inkling that I should be doing some sort of mail merge and displaying the result to the user for printing but I don't know how I'd go about getting the screen laid out correctly for the labels. Should I be creating some kind of PDF and displaying that? If so how would I go about doing so?

This is all very new to me so any help would be much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: We had a web based app for our dispatch system and used a network capable, dedicated label printer. This came with an API for developing and using lables. As it prints 1 label at a time (quickly) there is no need to specify a label on a sheet. The learing curve was a little steep, but once it was set up it worked perctly.

Comment: All client side stuff is javascript not classic asp which runs on the server.

Comment: @JonP That sounds great but a little over the top for our needs. Only 5-10 labels are printed each day and people sometimes take labels off the sheets for other needs

Comment: @Dee I'm aware that Classic ASP is server side only, I have the ability to add extra ASP pages to the server. The only reason I mention JavaScript is that I'm restricted to using JavaScript within the ASP pages rather than VBScript

Comment: "I have no idea how I should go about printing the label"  This printing is all going to be client side stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At FVI we have the same issue and solved it as old school as it gets.
First we created a rtf document of the label we wanted.  In this template we had key words in the file such as @@CUSTOMER@@ and @@ADDRESS01@@.

Step one was opening the template into memory, text substitute the key words and save to a web link for opening and printing.

By making a new RTF file on the fly we did not have to worry about the software on the other end of the connection.  we just presented our factory with a correctly formatted response that fit to the printer definition we had established.

Thus on the web page it has a select option for label type and that loads the correct template into memory for final output.

Not the best way to do it, but it cost us only 1 day of layout and simple html programming and zero issues with our China Factories.

Comment: To address multi part labels we would load in a header section, a body section and an ending section.  Thus we were able to loop the body section making a correct page layout and then closed the document with a correctly formatted ending section.

Comment: Thanks for your help. RTF was a pain to learn but it did the job!

Comment: It is an old technology but it works in a pinch.